# How to summarize data set in less than 100 bytes?

Tags: dataset, aggregation, extreme-value

I'm in the beginning of a process learning to using accelerometer data to measure how good/bad a person drives a car (driver's behaviour). I want to decompose the acceleration into breaking, forward acceleration, sideways acceleration (cornering) and vertical acceleration. But I'm unaware of the sensor's physical orientation.

What I do is to take the average reading from when the device is not moving and use this as the gravity. The I project the acceleration vectors on a plane orthogonal to the gravity. For a five minute driving trip, this can look like this:

[image: Each point is a reading from the accelerometer in m/s^2 projected to a plane orthogonal to the gravity vector]

In the long term, I want to be able to determine the driving direction from this. Often it is easy, as the breaking acceleration usually is the largest. But not in this case. So for now I just want to describe this data set in a best possible way in 100 bytes or less. The accelerometer is on a separate device, and there are limitations on data traffic.

What I have done is to update a table from 0 to 359 degrees with maximum values for each angle. But this is influenced too much by atypical values. The average may be a good alternative, or both. But I am not a statistician and I imagine that someone who is knows better ways to do this.

So the question is how to describe/summarize this data set in 100 bytes or less. It won't be exact of course, but any improvements are welcome!

edit:
Here is the data set itself. This is the raw readings from the sensor: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19L3iw3kzeoyvHeOWLyhu7-T5dpxA63DIXZPQKRaG21o/edit?usp=sharing

And see sheet 2 in the same document for another data set, driving a straight line accelerating normally and then breaking hard. (And repeating this pattern 3 or 4 times). In this data set it is very easy to see the breaking direction with max values.

edit 2:
I'm reading about skewness and kurtosis. Are those relevant here? Also I'm researching "circular regression", i.e. finding a best fit circle or ellipse for these points. Is that a good way to go?

Comment: The data look plausibly bivariate normal so a good starting point would be the means and covariance matrix, but if you could post a sample dataset itself that would be better. Moreover, the question is a bit confusing because you don't state what programming language you want to use. What compilers or run-time interpreters do you have access to ? In R you could simple do colMeans(X);var(X) if the data are contained in the matrix X

Comment: Thanks!
I'm a C# programmer, but this has to be done i plain C. I will post a data set.

Comment: OK great. So on this site we can advise you about what statistics you could calculate. If you have a specific question about how to implement it in C, then you can ask on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have no problems implementing stuff, it is the statistics that is the challenge to me.

Comment: The display doesn't account for how the changes go over time; for example there's a big difference if there's a lot of criss-crossing of the space (changing from hard acceleration to deceleration for example) than if there's a slow progression across and back. But I'd look at time series plots (especially if you can discern a preferred direction) to start with; that might suggest suitable summaries.

Comment: Thanks. That's true. The readings from the accelerometer fluctuates quickly from one direction to another, so there seems to be quite a bit of noise.

Anyway, my goal is the make a score for a trip, and so far I hope to it simply from the total set of values, not considering the order of the readings. But it might be hard.

Comment: I would be interested to see other datasets which give examples of other erratic driving behaviour. Is it correct that the first dataset shows "good" driving ? The most obvious thing I noticed between the 2 datasets so far is that x is roughly normally distributed in the first datset, while in the 2nd it is very far from normal and also has a variance 6 times larger, while the variance of z is 11 times smaller. skewness and kurtosis may be relevant, but I'd like to see some more data, if possible

Comment: Great - thanks! I added two more sets in new tabs in the same document. But this is all with the same car and driver. So with other cars and drivers, the data might be quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like calculating the covariance matrix is a good solution. Only remaining problem is how to do it incrementally, during one pass through the data (without storing all of the data.). But I guess that is a question for Stack overflow.

Comment: A new question about how to design an efficient algorithm to compute a variance-covariance matrix would be on topic here, I believe, though a question about how to implement it in a specific language would not.